# CSS selector that applies only to elements with two or more instances of a string in an attribute?

Tags: css

So I have elements like

```
<div data-key="test"></div>
<div data-key="test_1"></div>
<div data-key="test_1_2"></div>
```

I can write the following CSS to apply styling to some them

```
div[data-key*="_"]{color:red;}
```

The text in test_1 and test_1_2 will appear red because of this CSS.

What I need to figure out is how to apply different styling to the other elements where there are more underscores. So I could make test_1_2 blue for example.

The values in the data-key attribute are always in the following format:

- test
- test_1
- test_1_2
- test_1_2_3

The underscore never appears at the start or end.

Comment: There is no way to implement any sort of "counting" using that attribute selector. (Even if you were to repeat it a second time, `div[data-key*="_"][data-key*="_"]`, that would only increase the specificity of the selector, but not change what it matches.)

Comment: Any special reason you can't add classes (or some other attribute(s)) to represent the different styles you need?

Comment: The HTML is generated by a 3rd party plugin and it doesn’t offer the option to attach classes or attributes to the elements in question. I was hoping to avoid looping through them with JS - but looks like that’s my only option.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you in the case you described:
`div[data-key*="_1_"]{color:red;}`
This won't catch any two underscores, only the sequence "_1_", but maybe it's enough for your requirements.

Comment: The strings aren’t that predictable unfortunately. They appear more like word_anotherword_randomword